# Confused on proof of closed intervals being compact in order topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am looking at the proof of theorem 27.1 in Munkres which states: Let $X$ be a simply ordered set having the least upper bound property. In the order topology, each closed interval in $X$ is compact.

In the proof it says first prove the following: If $x$ is a point of $[a,b]$ different from $b$, there is a point $y>x$ of $[a,b]$ such that the interval $[x,y]$ can be covered by at most two elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

I am confused by the last line, when it says the interval $[x,y]$ can be covered by at most two elements of $\mathcal{A}$. Wouldn't the collection $\mathcal{A}$ itself cover the interval $[x,y]$, and $\mathcal{A}$ possibly has more than two elements? What does it mean to say that $[x,y]$ can be covered by at most two elements from $\mathcal{A}$? Does it mean it can be covered by at most two elements from $\mathcal{A}$ such that the union of the two elements is exactly equal to $[x,y]$ and not just a set containing $[x,y]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that either there is an $A\in\mathscr{A}$ such that $[x,y]\subseteq A$, or there are $A_1,A_2\in\mathscr{A}$ such that $[x,y]\subseteq A_1\cup A_2$. In other words, you need at most $2$ elements of $\mathscr{A}$ in order to cover the interval $[x,y]$. The cover definitely does not have to be exact and generally will not be: in general it will cover more than the interval $[x,y]$.